# mysql: Unknown Column Error in Query

Tags: mysql, shell

I was writing this query into a shell script so all the double quotes are escaped and there timestamps are variables.

This query works if i don't use the "order by" on terminal.

also there is a strange thing that if the execute the query part in the `PHPMYADMIN` then then `"order by`" works.
but if i run this query in terminal it gives me `UNKNOWN COLUMN QID error`

```sql
SELECT 'GUIDE-NAME','QUESTION-ID','ACTION','TIMESTAMPS' 
UNION 
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(B.msg,LOCATE('q_id',B.msg)+5, (LOCATE('\"',B.msg)+2) ) AS qid, B.ts 
FROM TABLE B, TABLE A 
WHERE 
       LOCATE('q_id',B.msg) > 0 
       AND A.g_id=B.g_id and B.ts > from_unixtime($DateWeekBefore) 
       AND B.action 
       IN(\"review_question\",\"send_back",\"send_review\",\"publish\",\"quiet_publish\")  
ORDER BY qid 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/$vr9$DateWeek.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: There is an additional problem with this , after escaping the Double Quotes now it is not producing the results .without escaping it is producing results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL tries to apply `order by` on all query, not on a sub-select. In order to separate sub-selects use brackets:

```
(select ....) union (select.... order by something)
```

It seems that `INTO OUTFILE` can't be used directly in unions, so we need to make a union as a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    (
        SELECT 'GUIDE-NAME','QUESTION-ID','ACTION','TIMESTAMPS'
    ) UNION (
        SELECT.... ORDER BY qid
    ) 
) a 
INTO OUTFILE ....
```

Comment: Now it is giving this error :-> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/Send-For-Review-2011-07-22-1311358743.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED ' at line 1

Comment: @shobhit Hmm. It seems that `INTO OUTFILE` can't be used directly with unions. Do something similar (but a little differently) as _TehShrike_ said: `select * from ( (select ....) union (select.... order by something) ) a INTO OUTFILE ....`

Comment: I am getting this ERROR 1248 (42000) at line 1: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: I tried this ---->  SendForReview=" SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'GUIDE-NAME','QUESTION-ID','ACTION','TIMESTAMPS') UNION (SELECT A.g_name, SUBSTRING(B.msg,LOCATE('q_id',B.msg)+5, (LOCATE('\"',B.msg)+2) ) AS qid, B.action, B.ts from gsite_log B, g_profile A where LOCATE('q_id',B.msg)>0 and A.g_id=B.g_id and B.ts>from_unixtime($DateWeekBefore)and B.action IN(\"review_question\",\"send_back_to_guide\",\"send_for_review\",\"publish\",\"quiet_publish\") ORDER BY qid ) INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/$vr9$DateWeekBefore1.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"

Comment: @shobhit Look carefully into my last comment. You forgot to add an alias (in my comment this was `a`). And also you forgot to add some brackets :)

Answer (score 0):

qid is an alias. Instead of

```
ORDER BY qid
```

Try this:

```
 ORDER BY SUBSTRING(B.msg,LOCATE('q_id',B.msg)+5, (LOCATE('\"',B.msg)+2) )
```

Edit: My guess is PHPADMIN is smart enough to see that it's an alias and translates it, whereas the terminal does not.

Comment: This would be a problem for an query performance but may be this is a one way to do it via shell

Comment: i agree that it is an alias but why did phpmyadmin accepted that alias? it shouldn't have worked there too

Answer (score 0):

As Karolis noted, that ORDER BY is only being applied to the second query in your UNION.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
 [your whole query]
) AS some_subquery
ORDER BY qid
INTO OUTFILE ...
```

Comment: i tried but now it is giving error ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/Send-For-Review-2011-07-22-1311358743.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED ' at line 1

Comment: @shobhit - I'm in the MySQL chat room, if you'd like to talk more efficiently http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/592/mysql

Comment: "(SELECT 'GUIDE-NAME','QUESTION-ID','ACTION','TIMESTAMPS') UNION (SELECT A.g_name, SUBSTRING(B.msg,LOCATE('q_id',B.msg)+5, (LOCATE('\"',B.msg)+2) ) AS qid, B.action, B.ts from gsite_log B, g_profile A where LOCATE('q_id',B.msg)>0 and A.g_id=B.g_id and B.ts>from_unixtime($DateWeekBefore)and B.action IN(\"review_question\",\"send_back_to_guide\",\"send_for_review\",\"publish\",\"quiet_publish\") order by) INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/$vr9$DateWeekBefore1.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"

Comment: I cannot talk in chat room bec i dont have much reputation , i just started following stackoverflow .Here is my full query which works fine without order by

Comment: Ah, it looks like Karolis was able to state the answer in a way you could understand.

Comment: yes. simply because it was not only the problem of brackets, it was much more than that. It was like a concept for me which he cleared very well. :)